# Archived project not in Organizer; found in Finder, but file is 0 bytes

Tags: xcode, archive

I archived my project, and browsed to Window>Organizer>Archives, but I don't see the archived file. Therefore I am unable create an .ipa file of my project.

I had another project with me, so I archived that, and suprisigly it worked. So I right-clicked on the Archived file and selected "Open in Finder". There I found my previously archived file (The one that didn't appear in Organizer>Archives). It says the size of it is zero bytes. What does this mean?

How do I solve this?

I have selected iOS device from the Target pop-up then simulator, and also added "Yes" to Skip Install as suggested in this [blog post](http://www.weston-fl.com/blog/?p=2429).

Comment: "Build & Archive" is sometimes flakey for me.  What happens when you do just "Archive" from Xcode's "Product" menu?

Answer (score 7):

Changing Skip Install to **"NO"** works for me.

*I have selected iOS device from the Target pop-up then simulator, and also added "Yes" to Skip Install as suggested in this blog post.*

Comment: @ Thanks Serhats.  Changing Skip Install to "NO" also works for me

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if [this tutorial](http://soulwithmobiletechnology.blogspot.co.uk/2011/03/how-to-create-distribution-build-with.html) by Reetu Raj will help, though it does touch on archiving, & it's otherwise excellent reading.

Comment: I guess the tutorial discusses steps to create a distribution profile. But, i only need to Archive the project

Answer (score 1):

What Vern Jensen said is the right answer you need to make sure your "Installation Directory" is set to "/Application/".

Answer (score 1):

It took me 8 hours to solve the problem, tried all the solutions, and finally found that my Archives output hard disk was full...

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your archive scheme looks somewhat like this, based on what you're using the .ipa for
[image: Product --> Edit Schemes]

Product --> Edit Schemes

Comment: I only have 2 options in the drop-down, Release and Debug. Currently its in Release mode

Comment: when you are archiving does it say "Succeeded"?

Comment: Yes it did, but doesn't appear in the `Organizer-->Archived` Section. But when i goto `Xcode-->Archived-->{date}` there it is, but the size is set to `Zero-Bytes`

Comment: Having the same issue. Other threads I've seen suggest making sure the "Installation Directory" property on my main target is set to something (not blank). It was blank on my project, so I set it "/Applications/" Lo and behold, it now WORKS!!!